# Javascript object return as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, javascript-objects

I am working on this script, where an $.ajax call, on success has to call a function, which should return a Javascript object as JSON in the format `[object object]`, so that I can access it in success body. I am able to return a nicely formatted string, but I can't access object's properties. This is the actual body of `[object object]`:

```
{"id":"12","created_at":"2015-10-30T21:30:44.457Z", 
"card":{"id":"67","number":"89990","expires":"2018"},
"verification":"required"}
```

Its like an object within an object of JavaScript. first object is called employee, and nested object is called card. I can't understand what wrong I am doing. I tried to define object in literals as this:

```
function get_employee()
{
var employee = [];
var employee_data = '[{"id":"12","created_at":"2015-10-30T21:30:44.457Z", 
"card":[{"id":"67","number":"89990","expires":"2018"}],
"verification":"required"}]';
employee = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(employee_data));
return employee;
}
```

This is how I want to access it in $.ajax call:

```
$.ajax {
type: "POST",
url: 'my_url/process',
//etc etc
success: function(data){
//calling my get_employee function now
params = get_employee();
//this is how I want to use the returned object as JSON
frm = $("<form action='/save/employee/database' method='POST'></form>");
frm.append("<input type='hidden' name='employee_id' value='" + params.employee.id + "'>");
frm.append("<input type='hidden' name='card_id' value='" + params.card.id+ "'>");
frm.append("<input type='hidden' name='request_id' value='" + data + "'>");
frm.submit();
}
}
```

But when I console.log(params.token.id) I get an error, saying params.token.id is undefined, also the same error in the form. My question is: how should I do this? What am I missing?

**NOTE:** when I console.log(params), it prints the plain string as I have defined in the function, but it doesn't return [object object]. When I debug in firebug, it also displays the returned response as an html string instead of JSON. My problem is I want to receive it as JSON and also access its properties as a normal javascript object.

Thanking in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would get the JSON data from the ajax call, like this:

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: 'my_url/process',
    dataType: 'json',                // !
    success: function(data) {        // Now, data will be an Object
        ...
    }
} )
```

and your server at `my_url/process` just returns the JSON string.

However, if you want to use your `get_employee` to return an object, there is no need to use JSON.parse: just use JavaScript Object Notation to declare the object:

```
function get_employee()
{
    return {
       employee: {
           id: 12,
           created_at: "2015-10-30T21:30:44.457Z",
           card: { id:"67", number":"89990", expires:"2018" },
           verification:"required"
       }
    };
}
```

Also, besides fixing various syntax errors, make sure you access the card properly:

```
frm.append("<input type='hidden' name='card_id' value='" + params.employee.card.id+ "'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `employee_data` is already a JSON string, there is no need to `.stringify()` it again otherwise it will escape the string again and as result the `.parse()` method will return you the original JSON string instead of the object you wanted.

Comment: Hi @Kenney thank you for explaining this. I am going your way and trying to test it. However, it gives me a syntax error inside the object literals at `created_at: time_stamp` field. Please note that `time_stamp` is a variable which contains current time and date. I am sure its allowed to pass variables as values of the keys. whats wrong here?

Comment: Hi @Griffith  Thanks for this. You are right that its already a JSON. Now, if I don't json.prase it, i get an error when I used the variable as a value of the key in object literals. this way:
`employee: { id: id, created_at: time_stamp }` am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much both you guys. This really worked :)